# JQuery UI .effect() and .toggle(): call start function like on JQuery .animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working with animations, and on my webpage there's many animations happening at the same time. I need to play audio when some animations begin, and to display certain things when certain animations end.

In the past, I've used JQuery's `.animate()`, which contains callbacks for both start and end of the animation:

```
.animate({
    //css here
  }, {
    start: function(){}, //called on start of animation
    complete: function(){}, //called on end of animation
  });
```

That was really neat and useful, and worked like a charm, without the need to call setTimeouts with the respective animation duration.

But now I need some more advanced animations, and JQuery UI effects have been satisfactory, until the point that I need to use start callbacks again: [On JQuery UI .effect() API page](https://api.jqueryui.com/effect/) only the `complete:` callback exists. Fooling around with JQuery UI source i've found that it uses `.animate()` to do things, so it seems that it would be possible to make some changes to it and add a `start:` option, but I don't want to mess with the source code (unless it's simple and wouldn't do some damage), and don't want to recreate every effect with `.animate()` only.

Is there any way to have `start:` on JQuery's UI `.effect()` and `.toggle()`? Or should I use a completely different API that supports it? Any recommendations? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that GSAP's TweenMax is way better at animations than JQuery UI, and does everything that I need: animations, events, callbacks,  timeline, everything.

Link: https://greensock.com/gsap